# I'm looking for a manga that has a strong magician that lives in the woods

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

So the magician is either avoiding the capital or is being hunted by them. He is all **alone**, lives by himself in a **log cabin**. It might be an isekai or he is a very talented magician, **huge** magic circles. I'm pretty sure he uses a gigantic one to destroy an army or to purify a lake. I remember very well he lives by himself in a log cabin and was overpowered.

Edit with more details. I read this a while ago but I have a strong feeling I'd remember what he would look like especially if it was near a lake or log cabin.
I had read this in the past 5-6 years it was in English and I had just stumbled upon it online when looking for manga.
I remember things going on here and there, I won't say it was more action based nor slice of life. He would fight then do his own thing, then someone or something might show up he'd do whatever needed to be done then go back to whatever he was doing.
He had longer hair but not to the shoulders, he had black hair, he wore more fantasy medieval clothes kinda like a cloak.  I can't remember any colors on the clothes, I know he fought some humanoid monsters but don't want to say he was looking to fight them. I can't remember any specifics regarding the monster besides that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you describe the magician's appearance, in terms of his hair colour/length, and colour/style of his clothing? Also, can you describe any specific opponents that he fought?

Comment: As @LogicDictates says we can better help with more details, like when you read this and what language it was in? Can you [edit] in any of the details from this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and while we have you please do take the [tour] and use the [help] to answer any further question you have about the site.

Comment: @Explicit Do you remember if it was an action-oriented manga, or more laid back like slice of life? He lives alone, but does he have any frequent visitors or companions?